# not able to connect to the TFS using asp.net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tfs

trying to connect to the TFS server using below code and getting exception.

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
credentials.Domain = "domain";
BasicAuthCredential basicCredentials = new BasicAuthCredential(credentials);
TfsClientCredentials cred = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCredentials);
cred.AllowInteractive = false;
var _tfsTeamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("mytfsurl));
_tfsTeamProjectCollection.Authenticate();
```

Exception : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

same code works fine with the console application.

Comment: Does it work if you add this line beforehand, or in Global.asax?: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Comment: Which version of TFS do you use? Could you please try the following code: `var myCredentials = new VssClientCredentials(); var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(@"http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"), myCredentials);`?